# Playframework: routes entry to an external URL

Tags: redirect, routes, playframework

I want the following redirection functionality

```
GET /google    google.com
```

How should I implement this?

Comment: I would not recommend mapping a local path to an external URL, it's misleading and not the standard navigation experience. I would just add a link to Google where you need it.

Comment: Pere, google.com was just an example. We have two internal domain sites...lets say main site and a blog site (under a diff domain and maintained by a separate team). I'd just like a simple redirect of domiain.com/blog to go to blog.com

Comment: even thought, if it's external to the application (so it will have its own path) I would not use routes for that. Routes is for paths of the app itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not seem it is possible to do that straight from the routes files [at this moment](https://github.com/fgutmann/play/blob/872ed4834a9e502709040b336ec60824154ee915/framework/src/play/mvc/Router.java).

You could implement this in a controller:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

 public static void google() {
    redirect("http://www.google.com");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is the best solution so far (other than fronting an apache/web server). Not sure how much resources can be saved if the routes can handle this case

Comment: From an SEO point of view, when redirecting off-domain I would strongly recommend using `redirect("http://www.google.com", true);`, which will indicate to search bots that the content has moved permanently to the new location, instead of temporarily (HTTP code 301 instead of 302). Very detailed discussion of 302 redirects [here](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-discussing-302-redirects/).

Comment: Direct redirect from routes also available: `GET /main controllers.Default.redirect(to = "http://google.com/")`

Answer (score 8):

```
GET /google    controllers.Default.redirect(to = "http://google.com/")
```

(Re-post of FoREacH's comment because it's worth being here as an answer)